# How to get selected item from custom ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom ListView where each row consists of a number of TextViews inside it. When I click on the ListItem, the `OnListItemClick()` doesn't get called. So how do you get the selected of a custom list view?

Thanks for your help!

**XML for Row:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/priorityView"
        android:layout_width="20dip"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#cccccc"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dip" />


    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1.0"
        >
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingLeft="5dip"
        android:paddingRight="5dip"
        android:paddingTop="2dip"
        android:text="@string/empty"
        android:textSize="20dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/monthText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text="@string/empty"
        android:textSize="10dip" >
    </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text="@string/empty" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:text="@string/empty"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" >
    </TextView>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/selectedCheckbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dip" >
    </CheckBox>

</LinearLayout>
```

**XML for ListView:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
    </ListView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {


    private AppointmentsDB dbHelper;
    private Cursor cursor;
    private AppointmentsCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dbHelper = new AppointmentsDB(this);

        StringBuilder selectQuery = new StringBuilder();
        selectQuery.append("SELECT "+AppointmentsDB.KEY_ID+",");
        selectQuery.append(AppointmentsDB.KEY_TITLE + ", ");
        selectQuery.append(AppointmentsDB.KEY_DESCRIPTION + ", ");
        selectQuery.append(AppointmentsDB.KEY_PRIORITY + ", ");
        selectQuery.append(AppointmentsDB.KEY_DATE_TIME + ", ");
        selectQuery.append(AppointmentsDB.KEY_DURATION + ", ");
        selectQuery.append(AppointmentsDB.KEY_ALARM_TIME + " FROM "
                + AppointmentsDB.DATABASE_TABLE + " ");
        selectQuery.append("ORDER BY " + AppointmentsDB.KEY_DATE_TIME + " ASC");

        cursor = dbHelper.openReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
                selectQuery.toString(), null);

        String[] columnNames = new String[] {  };
        int[] ids = new int[] { };

        cursorAdapter = new AppointmentsCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.row, cursor, columnNames, ids);
        this.setListAdapter(cursorAdapter);
    }

    // This class sets our customised layout for the ListView
    class AppointmentsCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

        private int layout;
        private int[] colours;

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public AppointmentsCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
                String[] from, int[] to) {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to);


            this.layout = layout;
            colours = new int[] {
                    context.getResources().getColor(R.color.light_gray),
                    context.getResources().getColor(R.color.green),
                    context.getResources().getColor(R.color.orange),
                    context.getResources().getColor(R.color.brick_red) };
        }

        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View view = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);

            TextView titleText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titleText);
            TextView priorityView = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.priorityView);
            TextView dateText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dateText);
            TextView monthText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.monthText);
            TextView timeText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timeText);

            String title = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(AppointmentsDB.KEY_TITLE));

            int priority = 0;
            String _priority = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(AppointmentsDB.KEY_PRIORITY));
            if(_priority != null)
                priority = Integer.parseInt(_priority);

            long dateTime = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(AppointmentsDB.KEY_DATE_TIME)));

            Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(dateTime);

            SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "dd,MMM,HH:mm aaa");
            String[] tokens = timeFormat.format(calendar.getTime()).split(",");
            dateText.setText(tokens[0]);
            monthText.setText(tokens[1]);
            timeText.setText(tokens[2]);

            titleText.setText(title);
            priorityView.setBackgroundColor(colours[priority]);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

            TextView titleText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titleText);
            TextView priorityView = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.priorityView);
            TextView dateText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dateText);
            TextView monthText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.monthText);
            TextView timeText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timeText);

            String title = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(AppointmentsDB.KEY_TITLE));
            int priority =0;
            String _priority = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(AppointmentsDB.KEY_PRIORITY));
            if(_priority != null)
                priority = Integer.parseInt(_priority);


            long dateTime = Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(AppointmentsDB.KEY_DATE_TIME)));

            Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(dateTime);

            SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "dd,MMM,HH:mm aaa");
            String[] tokens = timeFormat.format(calendar.getTime()).split(",");
            dateText.setText(tokens[0]);
            monthText.setText(tokens[1]);
            timeText.setText(tokens[2]);

            titleText.setText(title);
            priorityView.setBackgroundColor(colours[priority]);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put the layout xml from both the list and the list item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution.

You have to set the `android:focusable` attribute to `false` for each widget inside the custom `ListView`, including the Layout widgets.

Answer (score 0):

Try using`OnItemClick()` instead of `OnListItemClick()`,

This is the Custom listview created by `SimpleCursorAdapter` by sending cursor

```
        SimpleCursorAdapter yearadapter =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listview, yearcursor, yearfrom, yearto);
        setListAdapter(yearadapter);
        amount.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {

                  //Your code when item get clicked
                 }
            });
```

It should work.

Comment: My class subclasses ListView. There is no OnItemClick method to override.

Comment: So you should have the setOnItemClickListener() method, use it to register a new OnItemClickListener and put whatever you want to do when an item is clicked in the onItemClick() method, like Venture wrote.

Comment: Sorry, I meant it subclasses ListActivity. I can't override that method.

Comment: If so, Just change it as Activity and add two line of onitemClick()  code. It will do the magic

Answer (score 0):

Below code will give you the list view item:

```
   private ListView listView = (ListView) findviewbyid(.........);

       listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            View v = v.getChildAt(arg2);//This will give the listview item


        }
    });
```